# How to call method on specific time?

Tags: android

I have the folowing code:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
}
```

How can I use it to execute method "onLed();"

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @https://stackoverflow.com/users/9947965/theodor-radu
Can you please provide bit more information on this?

Comment: What exactly do you wanna do?

Comment: What is onLed() here?

Comment: Not sure want your goal is. But to do a task at a specific time try using AlarmManager (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager)

Comment: I use it to send a string via bluetooth to a controller

Comment: I tried using AlarmManager but for this I need something like an alarmReceiver fragment from which I don t know how to execute that method.

Comment: Ok...but for this I need a different class that receive the alarm. I don't know how to call "onLed();" from that new class. I have no experience in Java.

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use this code:
private static class MyTimeTask extends TimerTask
{

    public void run()
    {
        //write your code here
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //the Date and time at which you want to execute
    DateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = dateFormatter .parse("2012-07-06 13:05:45");

    //Now create the time and schedule it
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    //Use this if you want to execute it once
    timer.schedule(new MyTimeTask(), date);

    //Use this if you want to execute it repeatedly
    //int period = 10000;//10secs
    //timer.schedule(new MyTimeTask(), date, period );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    long timeToWait = System.currentTimeMillis() - c.getTimeInMillis();
    if(timeToWait > 0) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                onLed(); //This function will execute after spending your time
            }
        }, timeToWait);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your time.